# How to get the LineNumber and Method name inside Exception

Tags: asp.net, exception

So i have a function which in turns call a method that take Exception object as the parameter.

```
public DataSet SomeFunction()
{    
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            ErrorLogInDB.LogError(ex);
            throw;
    }
}

public static void LogError(Exception exception)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exception, true);
    StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(0);

    MethodBase site = exception.TargetSite;

    string fileName = frame.GetFileName();
    string methodName = site.Name;
    int lineNo = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    string errorDescription = exception.Message;
}
```

From the above function `LogError` i am getting `filename` as `null`, `methodname` is incorrect and also the `line number`. How to solve it?

Comment: The code you provided cannot throw exception, there is now way to tell what is wrong from this

Comment: @codingbiz let the `try` block generate any `exception`...it gives me incorrect result when trying to log the error inside `datatbase`.

Comment: Do you have `.pdb` file in environment where you try to log this error? This file contains metadata used by `StackTrace` class to provide extended source info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try...

```
StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(exception, true);
StackFrame stackFrame = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1);
string fileName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
string methodName = stackFrame.GetMethod().Name();
int lineNo = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Comment: @user2322507: Compare your `new StackFrame(0)` with `trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1);`

Comment: `string methodName = site == null ? null : site.Name;` this line gives me the method name as 'OnError' when infact its `SomeFunction()`

Comment: @user2322507: what does `stackFrame.GetMethod().Name()` return?